How to use std::lower_bound when the key is part of the data and i want to search for the key?
I have a struct as follows:
struct chunk_offset {
    chunk_id chunk_id;
    unsigned int offset;
    unsigned int offset_size;
};
unsigned int chunk_count;
std::unique_ptr<chunk_offset[]> offsets;

I have a an array of these, sorted by chunk_offset::chunk_id.
since the data is sorted, I want to perform a binary search using std::lower_bound.
However, std::lower_bound expects a parameter that represents the object itself:
chunk read_chunk(chunk_id id) {
    // error, since id is not a chunk_offset
    auto itr = std::lower_bound(offsets.get(), offsets.get()+chunk_count, id); 
}

How can I use std::lower_bound with only my key?

Use the overload that takes an ordering predicate - #2 here. Use the predicate you defined for sorting. Or, you could define operator< for chunk_offset.

Use a comparator (or operator<) where the first parameter is chunk_offset and the second is chunk_id.

@interjay can you make this an answer?

When you call std::lower_bound(begin, end, value, comparator), it calls the comparator (or operator< by default) with the collection elements as the first parameter, and value as the second parameter. It's allowed for the two parameters to have different types.
So to get what you want, you can write a comparator with the signature bool compare(const chunk_offset &offset, chunk_id id) (or define operator< for those types).
For example, using a lambda:
auto itr = std::lower_bound(offsets.get(), offsets.get()+chunk_count, id,
    [](const chunk_offset &offset, chunk_id id) {
         return offset.id < id;
    });


did not know that you can use a predicate taking two different types

While (as the other answer says) you can give std::lower_bound a comparator with two different parameter types (as value is always the second parameter), in those cases I find it less confusing to use std::partition_point.
std::partition_point does the same thing, but uses an unary predicate and doesn't have a value parameter:
chunk_id id = ...;
auto iter = std::partition_point(a, b, [&](const chunk_offset &o){return o.chunk_id < id;});


C++20 ranges to the rescue (and cleaner code):
auto find(std::span<chunk_offset> data, chunk_id id)
{
    return std::ranges::lower_bound(data, id, {}, &chunk_offset::chunk_id);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/Gv6ahM3nT
BTW you have conflict of symbols: chunk_id (it is a type and field name).
